# SonarQube and Jenkins implementation

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I have a SonarQube server running in a different machine than Jenkins CI, my question is, Does SonarQube import the complete projects from Jenkins server or just use the reference? Because I could have a project of 1GB and it could makes low the connection, Can someone explain me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide any information about which version of SonarQube nor Jenkins you are using.

Still, I can answer your question regarding how Jenkins CI and SonarQube work together.

The basic idea is the following:

- Jenkin's Job checks out your project from Version control
- it then runs a local process (either a Sonar Runner task or a maven task, which uses Sonar Runner under the hood) which will analyse the project
- depending of the version of SonarQube you are using, the local process communicates either only with the SonarQube instance over HTTP(s) (in version SQ 5.2+) or also with the database used by the SonarQube instance
- project configuration, plugins and other meta stuffs are exchanged from SQ to the process local to Jenkins
- the result of the analysis (ie. issues, unit tests coverage, ...) and source code are exchanged from the local process to the SQ instance (and the Database)

So if your project is 1Gb big, then it will be a problem regarding SonarQube only if you have 1Gb of source code. If it was really the case, I doubt the SQ-Jenkins integration would be your first concern.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My SQ version is 5.1.2 and Jenkins CI is 1.620. But Basically this is my answer where Sonar executes the analysis, I've configure a Sonar Runner on the same machine where is Jenkins. But you have helped me a lot.!